# Why is terraform complaining about an argument not being expected when it is a valid argument in the documentation?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to upgrade my azurerm provider to 3.5.0 from 2.9.9. I am seeing the error:

`An argument named "namespace_id" is not expected here.`

My definition block is like this:

```
module "example-module" {
  source = "../../../../modules/azure-topic"

  name                = "blabla"
  resourcegroup_name  = module.rg-infrastructure.name
  servicebus_name     = module.servicebus.servicebus_name
  namespace_id        = module.servicebus.id
  enable_partitioning = false
}
```

I am using a custom module to create this topic. In the documentation for azurerm I see that `namespace_id` is a required argument. What I'm trying to do is upgrade from 2.9.9 to 3.5.0. The `namespace_id` has always been required so I don't know why I haven't seen this error before - it is only appearing when I actually upgrade the azurerm provider.

My topic module is as follows:

***main.tf***

```
resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "example_topic" {
  count                     = var.count_value
  name                      = var.name
  namespace_id              = var.namespace_id
  namespace_name            = var.servicebus_name
  enable_partitioning       = var.enable_partitioning
  enable_batched_operations = var.enable_batched_operations
}
```

***output.tf***

```
output "subscription_name" {
  value = azurerm_servicebus_subscription.service_bus_subscription.name
}

output "subscription_id" {
  value = azurerm_servicebus_subscription.service_bus_subscription.id
}
```

***variables.tf***

```
variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Subscription name"
}

variable "servicebus_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Servicebus name"
}

variable "topic_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Topic name"
}

variable "max_delivery_count" {
  type        = number
  description = "Maximum delivery count of the messages"
  default     = 3
}

variable "message_ttl" {
  type        = string
  description = "How long will the message live in the subscrption"
  default     = "P14D"
}

variable "message_lock_duration" {
  type        = string
  description = "Topic name"
  default     = "PT5M"
}

variable "enable_batched_operations" {
  type    = bool
  default = false
}

variable "topic_id" {
  type        = string
  description = "Topic id"
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error? Can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Your module variables.tf file does not specify `namespace_id` as an input variable, but you are providing one on your module instantiation.